# -= operator in jQuery's css method not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

It looks like jQuery's handling of `-=` in `css()` isn't working in IE8 for some reason. The following code doesn't through any errors, but it doesn't work either. I've narrowed it down to the operator mentioned above.

```
var postCount = $(".postsWrapper .window .posts article").length;
var numberOfPages = Math.ceil(postCount / 3);
var currentPage = 1;
var transitioning = false;
$(".postsWrapper button").click(function() {
    var direction = $(this).attr("data-direction");
    var postWindowWidth = $(".postsWrapper .window").width();
    if (direction == "next" && currentPage < numberOfPages && transitioning == false) {
        transitioning = true;
        // the below line does nothing in IE8
        $(".postsWrapper .window .posts").css("marginLeft", "-=" + postWindowWidth);
        setTimeout(function() {
            transitioning = false;
        }, 1000);
        currentPage++;
    } else if (direction == "previous" && currentPage > 1 && transitioning == false) {
        transitioning = true;
        // the below line does nothing in IE8
        $(".postsWrapper .window .posts").css("marginLeft", "+=" + postWindowWidth);
        setTimeout(function() {
            transitioning = false;
        }, 1000);
        currentPage--;
    }
});
```

See http://www.weblinxinc.com/beta/candy-controls/demo/site/index.htm

Comment: what does `-=` do in js?

Comment: That's not an operator, it's a relative CSS value (which is a wholly jQuery thing).

Comment: @CBroe: There's a `-=` in JavaScript, it does what `-=` does in C, C++, C#, Java, and various others. `a = 27; a -= 4; console.log(a); // 23` But the question above is about jQuery's `css` function, which accepts `-=` on values and handles it (nothing to do with JS's operator).

Comment: Seems to work to me everywhere but IE8, it might be a jQuery thing, I can never keep that straight.

Comment: @CBroe: wrong. there is, along with +=. The question is whether jquery's css engine recognizes it. @Rev: does the `+=` line work? It'd be very odd if M$ implemented `+=` but forgot `-=`, since they're basically the same thing.

Comment: No, neither `+=` or `-=` work.

Comment: @MarcB: It wouldn't be M$, it's handled in jQuery; IE8 will see the resulting value.

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes setting it to anything fixed works fine. This line of code, for example, works perfectly: `$(".postsWrapper .window .posts").css("marginLeft", "-20px");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `margin-left` property is starting out with the value `auto`, and so jQuery can't increment/decrement it. [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/fozem/1) (source below)

If you initially set it to a numeric value, it'll start working. [Live example](http://jsbin.com/fozem/2)

This might qualify as a jQuery bug, you might check [their list](http://bugs.jquery.com/) to see if it's there.

Here's the source to the live examples:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test">I'm the test div</div>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    // The following line is only in the second example, the one that works;
    // without it, it doesn't work (in IE8) even though it does in Chrome
    $("#test").css("marginLeft", 0);

    var counter = 0;
    var up = true;
    display("Initial marginLeft: " + $("#test").css("marginLeft"));
    setInterval(function() {
      if (up) {
        $("#test").css("marginLeft", "+=5");
      } else {
        $("#test").css("marginLeft", "-=5");
      }
      ++counter;
      if (counter > 10) {
        counter =0;
        up = !up;
      }
    }, 200);

    function display(msg) {
      $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting, that worked. Weird that it worked fine in every other browser. Thanks!

Comment: @Rev: Yeah, I figured it out by thinking "Why would an increment/decrement not work?" and answering "Because the value isn't a number" and so I dumped out the result of `.css("marginLeft")` on IE8 vs. Chrome and saw I got `auto` on IE8 and `0px` on Chrome (in my example).